# Defining the size of an array on a custom templated Array class

Tags: c++, c++20

I am making a project to write from scratch several datastructures, procedures, probably a mini-testing framework... things already well known and coded, but just with the purpose of learn and to adquire a much more deeper knowledge of the fundamentals of programming, but in a modern way, or, at least, using the modern tools of the `C++` language.

So, there's the repo for the code. [Zero](https://github.com/zerodaycode/Zero/tree/collections-array).
The code provided there is currently working under Unix systems, with `clang >= 14`.
Also, the repo contains a tool called `Zork`, that is a custom C++ project builder focused on build C++ project with the `C++20 modules` feature. On the root folder of the project, you will find a `zork++` file, that is the compiled binary for execute the tool. So, with just `./zork++` the tool will compile and link the project. That's an entry point as an ultra basic testing tool, that is just the `main.cpp` file calling the things and kind of testing it's funcionalities.

There's a `zork.conf` file, that is the configuration file to set up the commands that will be sent to the compiler to automate the project.

This spoiler is for provide the real code behind the question. I plan to make several questions on Stack Overflow for this project, so this one is setted as a base explanation for the "code example" required usually.

After this, let's go with the real question.

I started for make collections. Custom ones. So, for me, the very basic one (things should be the easy first ones, and then code to the most difficult ones in difficulty ascending order) is to simulate the C++ Array class.

This is the snippet:

```
export namespace zero::collections {
    template <typename T, unsigned long>
    class Array {
        private:
            T array[];
    };
}
```

First doubt is about the second parameter of the templated class. Second parameter must provide the desired initial capacity of the array member. I just choose long because is long enought to store any signed number (I guess that is too much...). I don't know the formal way in C++ of define this parameters that have real sense with the implementation.

A simple int would fit for most common cases. But I want to make it perfectly generic. I thought about constraint it with a concept. The idea is that parameter, must be an unsiged natural number. But not specifically a short, and int or a long. Something like `number`, for example. But I can't figure out the best way of code the requirement.

What could be the formal way of defining this requirement in modern C++, and use that template parameter to const initialize the array with a fixed size?

Comment: The standard way is to use a `std::size_t`  the same way `std::array` does

Comment: A `T array[];` class member is not valid C++.

Comment: "*so this one is setted as a base explanation for the "code example" required usually.*" Questions are not supposed to work that way. If information needs to be in the question, you ought to put it there.

Comment: @NicolBolas I have readily put the question object code inside Stack Overflow. Many times a complete example, or even a working code, is required. I have only laid the foundation so that, on future occasions, it will be easy for users to find the code and test their machines. I insist, as is often required. And, for the official documentation of Stack Overflow, you may want to deduce how "questions are supposed to work".

Comment: @NicolBolas *Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible*.

Comment: Should the array have a fixed size? Then name your size_t parameter, e.g. N, and use std::array<T, N>, if the size is variable, use std::vector<T>. Do you have reason to put those containers within a member variable or your Array class? If the official classes are suitable you can also give them other names within your namespace.

Comment: I was looking for some response reasoning about `size_t`. No, put official classes it's not suitable. I was looking to code it almost from scratch. It's a learning purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are looking for the `std::size_t`, which can be found on some system headers. Extracted from cppreference:

- Defined in header `cstddef`
- Defined in header `cstdio`
- Defined in header `cstdlib`
- Defined in header `cstring`
- Defined in header `ctime`
- Defined in header `cuchar`
- Defined in header `cwchar` (since C++17)

Basically, you should include one of them, and use `std::size_t` for the template parameter that must define the amount of elements that the user wants to store in the array.

```
export module your_module;

#include <cstddef>

export namespace zero::collections {
    template <typename T, std::size_t N>
    class Array {
        private:
            T array[N];
    };
}
```

Also note that you must define the size of the array member with the type parameter `N`.